# java.lang.ClassCastException whilst using JAVAFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I get the error "java.lang.ClassCastException". I'm trying to make a calculator and with JAVAFX (with SceneBuilder - if that's necessary), and I can't trace where I did wrong on the code.

I'm trying to make a new window appear when the button "HISTORY" is clicked and it should show all the previous operations performed.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: application.controller.MainWindowController cannot be cast to application.controller.HistoWindowController

MainWindowController is:

```
public class MainWindowController {

private Main main;

@FXML
TextField input1;
@FXML
TextField input2; 
@FXML
Label showAnswer;

public void setMain(Main main){
    this.main = main;
}
public void showAnswerSTR(String str) {
    showAnswer.setText("Answer:  " + str);;
}
@FXML
public void showHistory() {
    main.HistoryViewer();
}
@FXML
public void addNumbers(){
    Float inputA = Float.parseFloat(input1.getText());
    Float inputB = Float.parseFloat(input2.getText());
    Addition x = new Addition();
    String ans = x.operation(inputA, inputB);
    showAnswerSTR(ans);
}
@FXML
public void subtractNumbers(){
    Float inputA = Float.parseFloat(input1.getText());
    Float inputB = Float.parseFloat(input2.getText());
    Subtraction x = new Subtraction();
    String ans = x.operation(inputA, inputB);
    showAnswerSTR(ans);
}
@FXML
public void multiplyNumbers(){
    Float inputA = Float.parseFloat(input1.getText());
    Float inputB = Float.parseFloat(input2.getText());
    Multiplication x = new Multiplication();
    String ans = x.operation(inputA, inputB);
    showAnswerSTR(ans);
}
@FXML
public void divideNumbers(){
    Float inputA = Float.parseFloat(input1.getText());
    Float inputB = Float.parseFloat(input2.getText());
    Division x = new Division();
    String ans = x.operation(inputA, inputB);
    showAnswerSTR(ans);
}
}
```

HistoWindowController is:

```
public class HistoWindowController {

@FXML
VBox HistoryViewer;

public void showHistory(){
    StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(getHistory(),";");
    while(str.hasMoreTokens()){
        HistoryViewer.getChildren().add(new Label(str.nextToken().toString()));
    }
}

private String history = "H I S T O R Y;";

public void addHistory(String history) {
    this.history += history + ";";
}

public String getHistory() {
    return history;
}

/*public String historyReader() {

    StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(getHistory(),";");
    String temp = "";
        if(str.hasMoreTokens()) {
            temp += str.nextToken();
            temp += "\n";
        }
    return temp;
}*/
}
```

Main is:

```
public class Main extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/mainView.fxml"));
        AnchorPane mainFXML = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainFXML);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        MainWindowController mainWindow = loader.getController();
        mainWindow.setMain(this);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void HistoryViewer(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/HistoryView.fxml"));
        AnchorPane histoView = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(histoView);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        HistoWindowController histoControl = loader.getController();
        histoControl.showHistory();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess this is the line where it happens (check the stacktrace): `HistoWindowController histoControl = loader.getController();` ? What's the value of the `fx:controller` attribute in `HistoryView.fxml`?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Maybe you have a typo in `HistoryView.fxml` (like `MainWindowController` instead of `HistoWindowController` )  ?

Comment: @fabian I think that’s it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I guess this is the line where it happens (check the stacktrace): HistoWindowController histoControl = loader.getController();

the value of the fx:controller attribute in HistoryView.fxml is MainWindowController

Thanks @fabian